# uncompile6 in pip list but i can use it

Tags: windows, pip

I try install `uncompyle6` for decompyle .pyc file. I install it with `pip install uncompyle6`, so I can see it with `pip list`, but I recieve a message: "not recognized as an internal or external command". How can I fix it? My OS: Windows 10.

Comment: Compare `echo %PATH%` and `pip show --files uncompyle6`

Comment: I compared this ones and they are utterly different, that does it means? What variable I must add in PATH?

Comment: Add a full path to the `Scripts` directory from `pip show --files uncompyle6 | find "Scripts"`

Comment: This command returns me path like: ```..\Scripts\uncompyle6.exe``` so this is not full path...

Comment: Base directory is `pip show --files uncompyle6 | find "Location:"`

Comment: What name varPATH shoud have? I understand correctly that value of this variable is: ```..\Scripts\uncompyle6.exe``` or this variable must include 'location'? I would also like to ask where this folder 'Scripts' is located, it is not in the 'location' folder...

Comment: On `cmd.exe` terminal the command is `set PATH=C:\path\to\python\Scripts;%PATH%` Please be warned that `C:\path\to\python\Scripts` is just an example.